# Страница пользователя с ограниченными сообщениями

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Хочу создать страницу пользователя, на которой анонимные гости смогут задавать вопросы, а пользователь сможет на каждый вопрос дать один ответ, после чего ветка обсуждения будет деактивироваться.

Пока создал и связал две модели - `User` (`has_many :comments`) и `Comment` (`belongs_to :user`). Пользователи создаются, комментарии постятся.

Как сделать так, чтобы существовало ограничение типа "один вопрос - один ответ", и ответить мог сделать только владелец страницы, а не все подряд?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Ассоциация это всегда три составляющих: (1) у кого, (2) как и (3) что. (3) у вас пропущено :)

Answer (score 1):

Поместите вопрос и ответ прямо в модель Comment, пусть они хранятся в одной записи, но в разных полях. Анонимный пользователь будет создавать (create) запись Comment, а пользователь если захочет будет отвечать (update).

Возьмите для авторизации какой-нибудь известный гем, вроде [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), в нем есть все инструменты как для регистрации, входа, так и для проверки того, факта, что пользователь авторизован и ему можно предоставить возможности, недоступные для других пользователей.

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду разбираться с девайсом.

Comment: Спасибо, поправил.